# Installing GDAL 'frmts' on Windows

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w

I have a full OSGeo4W (64bit) installation on my Windows 10 laptop.
I'm using it for Quantum GIS, Python et cetera. There is a `osgeo4w64/apps/gdal-dev` folder in the installation.

I want to achieve this; http://www.cruisersforum.com/forums/f134/opencpn-13653-50.html#post322600

Which installs some extra packages ('`frmts`' from here; https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/trunk/gdal/frmts/bsb) and makes use of it. Now my question(s);

- what are these '`frmts`', some sort of plugins for GDAL?
- Are they already installed on my OSGeo distribution?
- If yes, where, so I can uncomment the line.
- How to download and install this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `frmts` directory is not a set of extra packages or plugins (though some drivers are implemented as a plugin if so defined in the makefile), it contains source code for all of GDALs raster drivers. Some are compiled by default, some aren't as they require third-party (sometimes proprietary) SDKs or libraries.

The [BSB driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#BSB) is compiled into GDAL by default (unless it has been disabled on purpose by the OSGeo4W build)

You can see if you have it by calling `gdalinfo --format BSB` from your OSGeo4W shell command prompt. You should see:

```
Format Details:
  Short Name: BSB
  Long Name: Maptech BSB Nautical Charts
  Supports: Raster
  Help Topic: frmt_various.html#BSB
  Supports: Open() - Open existing dataset.
  Supports: Virtual IO - eg. /vsimem/
```

Note that BSB support is **read-only** and you can't use OSGeo4W to install a **read-write** BSB driver.

What your linked forum post was doing was modifying the BSB driver to allow read-write access and then rebuilding GDAL.

You could do this yourself if you have the toolchain to build GDAL from source.  You would need a compiler, such as Visual Studio, and all the development sources/headers etc for GDAL and third-party libraries.  However, building GDAL is not easy if you have no experience in compiling native software from source.

If you want to try:

- [GDAL source](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource)
- See also the GDAL "src" [GIS Internals releases](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php) (pick the appropriate compiler version)
- And Windows [building instructions](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnWindows)

Comment: The current source code (GDAL 2.3) for the BSB driver can be found from https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/frmts/bsb

Comment: Thank you, that puts a lot in place.. As I now understand, I should get the source files, modify one file and then compile/build a new GDAL installation. I'll look into some 'build' tutorials......

Comment: Still, there is no easy guide to compile GDAL? Is it e.g. possible to let someone build it, and then transfer it to my computer?

Comment: @Willem, of course that's possible. That is how people deliver pre-compiled software. See also edit for more building details, though there's no easy guide because GDAL is a complex piece of software with many build options and lots of dependencies.